# What are some recommendations for a potted orange tree?

Tags: containers, tree-care, citrus

My wife and I would like to have a potted orange tree. We live in the San Diego area so the climate for citrus trees is near perfect, but we don't know what kind of tree we should buy. Also, how large of a pot, half a barrel size? Any other tips on the care and feeding would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something, but if you live in San Diego, why do you want a container citrus? Everyone else has to deal with setting fruit with limited light and winter protection, you just have to pick the one that you like the taste of most then buy the version that grows into the size that you have room for. Lucky...

Comment: We had two orange trees that were removed due to their size.  We don't have a lot of space so thought I'd ask to see if there were any other types that would grow in a container.

Comment: For most fruit trees, you can get most varieties grafted to a rootstock that will contol its size. I used a lot of "most's" because I only know of dwarf and standard citrus trees, but I suspect there are semi-dwarf citrus as well... Semi-dwarfs are very popular for stonefruits in my area.